# How to rename the columns of returned fields from Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a Django model called Hormone:

```
class Hormone:
  material = model.ForeignKey('Material',to_field='code')

class Material:
 code = model.integer()
 type = model.text()
```

I have a trouble to rename the intermediate result fields for the material meaning by using this syntax.

```
Hormone.objects.extra(select={"content":"material__meaning"}).values("content").all()
```

How do I correctly rename the key?

Thanks